# Java For each loop every instance from class

Tags: java

I start with OOP
And i have following problem:
I made a new class
Then I made ainstance from this class
Now, for every instance I want to do something
I tried it with a for each loop but it doesn't work...
There are some syntax problems

This is the class:

```java
package main;

public class command
{
    String call;
    String execute;
}
```

And this from the Main class:

```java
 private static void load() {
        command greeting = new command();

        greeting.call = "hello";
        greeting.execute = "Hello Sir";


        for (command c: command) {
            System.out.println("Another command...");
        }

    }
```

I don't know how to make the loop or is there another way to do it?

Comment: In order to use the `for each`, you need some kind of collection. Create, for instance, a `List` of commands, add 1 or more elements to this list and loop over that list.

Comment: To perform a iteration, you should put instances in array or `Iterable` container, e. g. `List`

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html

Comment: @Robert Kock I know but for this i must do this for every instance and that's too long because later I will create the instances from a xml file and then i've hundreds of instances. To do this automaticly i must go through the instances with a loop. And that's my problem

Comment: @TristanK. see the answer of Bastien. It's quite clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a static list inside class command that the instances get added to in the constructor(s).  Then you'll always have references to whatever instances are created.

Here's an example:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class command
{

    String call;
    String execute;

    public static List<command> commands = new ArrayList<>();

    public command() {
        commands.add(this);
    }

    public command(String call, String execute)
    {
        this.call = call;
        this.execute = execute;
        commands.add(this);
    }

    public String toString() 
    { 
        return "call: " + call + " | execute: " + execute;
    } 

}
```

Driver class:

```
public class driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i <=10; i++)
        {
            command c = new command("call" + i, "execute" + i);
        }

        for(command cmd: command.commands)
        {
            System.out.println(cmd);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you are using in your `for` loop must use a instance of a class that implements the `Iterable` interface. For example you can use implementations of the `List` interface.

For example, you can try:

```java
private static void load() {
    command greeting = new command();

    greeting.call = "hello";
    greeting.execute = "Hello Sir";

    List<command> listOfCommands = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfCommands.add(greeting);

    for (command c: listOfCommands) {
        System.out.println("Another command...");
    }

}
```

Comment: I know but for this i must do this for every instance and that's too long because later I will create the instances from a xml file and then i've hundreds of instances. To do this automaticly i must go through the instances with a loop. And that's my problem                                                                                                                  Ok later when i read them from a xml file i will put them automaticly in a array                         Thank you

Comment: Not sure to understand clearly what you want to do. If you want to store every instance of a class, so that you can easily access them later, you can use a `static` list, on which you would append every instance of the class when it's created, but I'm not sure it's what you're looking for.